# Is it possible to force Java to write all graphics output to FrameBuffer?

Tags: java, linux, graphics, framebuffer

For a personal project of mine, I'm trying to make java code written for a regular OS work on a linux OS I am currently developing, but I do not have an X11 or like system installed.  I would like to force a regularly programmed java program, into writing directly into the frame buffer.  I was thinking maybe there was a way I could capture Java's graphical output, and forward it to the framebuffer, and somehow synthesize the regular events such as KEY_TYPED and MOUSE_PRESSED?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080549/java-graphics-in-linux.
The goal of the questions is the same as yours.